# How to convert a date to uk time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date `2023-06-17T06:30:00.000Z` in Javascript, how can I convert it to something like `2023-06-17 06:30:00`, GMT in the winter and BST in the summer in UK time.

Comment: u can try put the time string in new Date() and use toLocaleTimeString() method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Comment: toUTCString() maybe better with this format https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have arbitrary timezones built in on most browsers. The only requirement is that they support UTC and local, which is what the popular engines do.
Something like `moment.js` could be used, but usually we only care about converting between UTC time zone and our LOCAL time zone, anyway, which is the local time for the user.

If what you really want is to convert from UTC to the users local time, the `Date` object has all you need.

`new Date(utcdatestring).toLocaleString()`

This also has the advantage of displaying the date and time in the format the local user is used to. You can play around with other options to change the format output:

`new Date(utcdatestring).toLocaleString("en-GB", { dateStyle: "short", timeStyle: "medium"})`

full list of options is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to display dates in any [`IANA timezone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

For your case, we'd use the timezone `Europe/London`, this will handle DST changes, using GMT in winter and BST in the summer.

```js
const timestamps = ['2023-06-17T06:30:00.000Z', '2023-12-17T06:30:00.000Z'];

for(let timestamp of timestamps) {
    const date = new Date(timestamp);
    const locale = 'en-GB';
    console.log('Timestamp:', timestamp)
    console.log('UTC Time: ',  date.toLocaleString(locale, { timeZone: 'UTC' }))
    console.log('UK time:  ', date.toLocaleString(locale, { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const date = new Date("2023-06-17T06:30:00.000Z")
const newDate = date.getFullYear().toString() +"-"+date.getMonth() + "-"+ date.getDate() +" " +date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
document.write(newDate)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).